# SQL populating added field rows with default value =0

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table with three fields:

```
ID|DESCRIPTION |PRICE
01|Item 1      |2.95
02|Item 2      |5.95
```

Now, more fields can be added to the end as supplier selling price.
What's the SQL query to default every existing item's selling price to 0 for this newly added field?

- List item

Answer (score 1):

For sql Server:

```
ALTER TABLE YOURTBL
        ADD sellingprice numeric(20,4) NULL 
        DEFAULT (0)
```

My SQL

```
ALTER TABLE YOURTBL ADD COLUMN sellingprice decimal(20,4) NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Oracle

```
ALTER TABLE YOURTBL 
ADD sellingprice  NUMBER(20,4) DEFAULT 0 NULL
```

MSAccess

```
ALTER TABLE YOURTBL ADD COLUMN sellingprice NUMBER DEFAULT 0
```

Comment: Not really, I was typing as i was coming to me... MAde them all null. Thanks

Comment: I'm using MS Access. In the above example table, if I need to add a field(SUPPLIER1) with and addition item3. The selling price for Item 1 and Item 3 must be zero(0) for this supplier.

Comment: I have added the example for msAccess

Answer (score 0):

is the current field Price the one you want to default to 0 for each new record? is so, then run this

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT df_Name DEFAULT 0 FOR Price
```

For a new field, this will create the field, and add 0 as the default

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD NewFieldName DECIMAL(10,4) DEFAULT(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE Table_Name
ADD supplier_selling_price INT NULL DEFAULT (0)
```

From DEFAULT Key word you can assign a default value to existing lines of newly added column. Please change the data type as per your need. (int, numeric, decimal)